# Configuring business logic tier from WCF Service Application

Tags: wcf, configuration, service, workflow, business-logic

I have a business logic tier I work with that requires configuration based on a custom configuration file. When using this tier within a web or windows application, I initialize the business logic tier within application startup, passing in the path to the configuration file which is configured in app.config or web.config.

I'm now trying to use this business logic tier within a WCF Service Application and am unsure of how to go about doing this as there is no 'application startup' point in a WCF Service Application. It should be noted that the workflows defined in the WCF service application are not directly interacting with the business logic tier, this is abstracted via calls to an activities dll, which then uses the business logic tier.

Thus, the architecture is something like this:

- WCFService uses ServiceActivities
- ServiceActivities consumes BusinessLogic, making external service calls depending on and using data provided by BusinessLogic.

How should I go about configuring my BusinessLogic layer in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

On a basic level, the application start-up is the zero-parameter constructor for the object identified in the service contract.